# requestAnimationFrame vs setinterval for game clock?

Tags: javascript, html

i am developing a HTML math game which have a clock to generate score based on it.
i am currently using requestAnimationFrame for clock. but the problem is that the clock stops when the user changes tab or the game tab becomes inactive. it should not be like that, the game clock shouldn't stop. so i am thinking to use setinterval() now .
so my question is there any performance inefficiency for using setinterval() instead of requestAnimationFrame ?

Comment: `setInterval` won't be any different, it will be throttled as well, when you change tabs. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oebc243n/2/). However, performance-wise, `requestAnimationFrame` will be better, because if the framerate goes low, it will not try to execute more times than it needs to (unlike `setInterval`)

Comment: Why not use the `Date` object? Get the date at the start and the end and work out the time between?

Comment: well i have to display clock time also so, that's why i can't use date method